# 110V outlet however machine is 3-phase 220V with ground

Tags: voltage

I recently bought a packing machine that is 220V three phase. The machine is from China and we are in Canada. The outlets here in Canada are 110V. The engineer from China says we are able to use the machine. However we are not sure. Can someone explain how we can achieve this?

This is the diagram the engineer from China gave us.

[image]

Comment: What is the nominal (k)VA rating, or (k)watts and power factor?

Comment: He's probably expecting you to have 3-phase power at your factory.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

[image]

*Figure 1. 3-phase voltages for high-leg transformer arrangement. Image source: [WaterHeaterTimer.org](http://waterheatertimer.org/What-is-high-leg-delta.html).*

Typical North American domestic supply is split-phase 120-0-120 as shown on the bottom of the three-phase diagram in Figure 1. As you can see there is no connection combination on those that can give you the high leg necessarry for proper three-phase supply.

If you are using this in an industrial facility or business premesis then there is a high likelihood that you have a three-phase supply and you should have a socket professionally wired close to your machine.

There may be a way of rewiring the machine to use single-phase but that would require examination by someone competent and has warranty implications.

Answer (score 1):

If you have residential power in Canada it is very unlikely you have 3-phase available. You may have ~240V available but it will be only single phase. 120:120 with a common neutral. This cannot be used to power 3-phase motors.

Most industrial units and larger industrial buildings will have 3-phase 60Hz available, though perhaps 600V. (347V phase-to-neutral .. analogous to the 480VAC with 277V phase-to-neutral more common south of the border). 600VAC 3phase 60Hz->240VAC 3-phase 60Hz can be handled with a simple transformer, but **not** single phase to three phase.

If it's from China it's also likely 50Hz. 50Hz devices will typically work on 60Hz, but may run a bit (like 20%) fast which could cause electromechanical problems with a fast packaging machine.

While it's possible to use a [rotary phase converter](https://www.americanrotary.com/phase-converters-canada) (no specific experience with this supplier) to get 3-phase 60Hz from single phase that's not terribly convenient. I have made a rotary phase converter from a surplus 10HP 3-phase motor, but that's even less convenient. You really need to check this kind of thing before ordering something that cannot be easily returned. The diagram you have shows 240V 3-phase. Folks trying to run industrial machines such as Bridgeports, large lathes or molding machines in their (residential) garage have similar problems (minus the Hz) issue.

Industrial machinery tends to use 3-phase motors where possible because they're relatively inexpensive and very reliable (no start or run capacitors to wear out). We don't have that option with single phase.

Comment: There are also non-rotary phase converters, more commonly known as VFDs or variable-frequency drives. They convert the incoming AC to DC and then electronically generate any kind of AC you want (hence variable-frequency).

Comment: @user253751 yes, I omitted mention of them because they are not necessarily suitable for powering an entire machine- the waveforms are choppy and they often depend on motor characteristics such as back-EMF to determine what to output. But if the supplier endorses it, it might be a solution.  Of course, coupled individually to any motor or motors plus a rewiring of the machine they could form part of the solution, but that might be beyond the present skill set of the OP.